# Is resource management a good idea when dealing with animations?

Tags: c#, unity, 2d, resource-management

New to the Unity environment here and I have a question concerning how to efficiently manage computer resources in a top down 2D game.  I have a large area that looks like a 2d rpg from the 90's and there are many water "tiles" that have an animation that plays constantly.  My question is: would it be a good idea to attach a script to the said water tiles to make them stop animating while the camera is not showing them?  The same question could be applied to any off screen animation that is currently running.  I guess what I'm not sure about is whether the constant testing for visibility is more "expensive" than the actual animation running.

Comment: All hypothetical performance questions have the same answer: profile it and find out! There are many things which will twitch the performance needle one way or another, but unless this is your main performance bottleneck (which depends sensitively on many details of your game and hardware which we Internet folk won't know without extended discussion), you might not see substantial gains from it. In this case, Unity's animation components have a "Culling Mode" setting that controls whether the animation plays when off-camera - try it each way and see if it makes a difference in your scenario.

Comment: I didn't know about the "culling mode".  Seems to be exactly what I need.  Thanks.